# Slowing motor and electric smoke coming from Magic Bullet blender?

Tags: equipment, blender

I have a Magic Bullet blender at home and I have been using it for the past month or so everyday to make some smoothies. I always blend fruit (both frozen and fresh). I'm not sure if the contents that are blended are related, but I've noticed the blending seems to have slowed down lately. The motor runs noticeably slower and the machine doesn't vibrate as much as it used to.

Has anyone had this experience? In addition, the blender has some smelly gas coming from the bottom, where there is a vent for the motor. Does this mean the unit is already wearing out? I only started using this a month ago, and I'd be surprised that it's already breaking.

Does anyone know what the gas signifies, even in other similar kitchen appliances?

Comment: Sounds like it's dead or dying.

Answer (score 6):

It's basically dead. The insulative enamel surrounding the wires in the motor has become overheated. That is where the smoke is coming from. If you continue to use the unit the enamel will degrade completely resulting in an electrical short. It is actually a bit of a fire hazard, so I would suggest discontinuing use of the unit.

It is possible that the unit is defective. Given its age I'm sure its covered under warranty. Early failure of electric motors can also be from excessive load. It may be that your unit is not intended to process something so substantial as ice. Another thing to note is that if the unit is jammed and cannot spin, you should release the power immediately. This is the fastest way to burn out any electrical motor. That goes for a cordless drill and the like.